IntelliSense does not detect XAML page if a parameter is passed to its constructor
Not sure if this is a bug or by design. As seen in the following images, PageTwo disappears from IntelliSense when a parameter is passed to its constructor. Of course I could just write PageTwo by hand, and it would work just fine, but this is inconvenient and might be error-prone, especially when IntelliSense is available and could accomplish the same task.
Update: This issue is not limited to Shell Page
With constructor parameter:


After removing constructor parameter:

Testing from another XAML page (PageTwo disappears):


I have the same issue with the latest VS preview, restart the project or build fixes it temporarily.

@MustafaMutasim, restarting or rebuilding didn't work in Visual Studio Community 2022 Ver 17.9.7 . The only way that works permanently so far requires removing the page parameter. But that is not a practical solution of course.

@usefulBee I reproduced your problem. Currently, this problem exists in the ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:}" of the AppShell.xaml file. In other .xmal files or .cs files, the Mainpage with construction parameters can be prompts normally through IntelliSense. You can go to VS to report this problem.

This issue has been fixed and being prepared for release. Therefore, I will mark it here as resolved.
